# Can I use variables in the PowerShell Replace method?

Tags: powershell, markdown

My goal is to run a PowerShell command that will update the text in a markdown table.

My project structure looks like:

/root
  
dashboardTable.md
  
replace.ps1

dashboardTable.md:

```
App Name | Build Version | QA Version | Prod Version
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
ProjectName  |0.0.0 | 0.0.0 | 0.0.0
```

replace.ps1

```
(Get-Content ./dashboardTable.md).replace('0.0.0', '0.0.1') | Set-Content './dashboardTable.md'
```

Running this command works and will change the markdown file to:

```
App Name | Build Version | QA Version | Prod Version
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
ProjectName  |0.0.1 | 0.0.1 | 0.0.1
```

I am trying to set a variable that can be used in place of the hardcoded values in the replace method, for example:

```
$MyVariable = '0.0.0'

(Get-Content ./dashboardTable.md).replace($MyVariable, '0.0.1') | Set-Content './dashboardTable.md'
```

But this changes my markdown file to:

```
App Name | Build Version | QA Version | Prod Version
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
0.0.1  |0.0.0 | 0.0.0 | 0.0.0
```

I even tried to switch the replace values around and run the PowerShell command like:

```
$MyVariable = '0.0.1'

(Get-Content ./dashboardTable.md).replace('0.0.0', $MyVariable) | Set-Content './dashboardTable.md'
```

And it changes the markdown to:

```
App Name | Build Version | QA Version | Prod Version
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
ProjectName  |ProjectName | ProjectName | ProjectName
```

Is it possible to use a variable like this?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue. Works perfectly fine for me. Both of your replace with `$MyVariable` should be working fine. You're setting content to the same file you are reading from, could that be the issue?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Hmm, that's strange. So in my project I only have two files, as described above. I have been copy and pasting the PowerShell script in to the PowerShell Integrated Console in VS Code. I'm not sure why that would work with no variables, then have the functionality change with them

Comment: To answer your question, if it's possible to use a variables with the `replace()` method, Yes, it's perfectly possible. I'm not sure why you would be seeing the results you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why I was getting the results I was getting however, I do know there was an issue when I was calling the PowerShell script.

To fix the issue, when I want to run the script, I run this command in the PowerShell Integrated Terminal:
`powershell -executionpolicy bypass ".\replace.ps1"` and was able to get the expected results.